# Undefined method `toggle!' for #:ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just got this problem in my controller, and I don't understand what's going on.
It returns an undefined method `toggle!` for `Like::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`: Or for my create action every thing works but not with the update action.
This is a basic like controller to like and unlike an event, someone and so on.

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @project=Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @like= @project.likes.where(user:current_user).first_or_initialize( name:current_user.first_name)
    @like.toggle(:heart)
    @like.save 
    Notification.create(user:current_user, user_name: current_user.first_name, action:'like', recipient:@project.subject)
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end



  def update
    @project=Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @like= @project.likes.where(user:current_user)
    @like.toggle(:heart)
    @like.save
    Notification.create(user:current_user, user_name: current_user.first_name, action:'Unlike', recipient:@project.subject) 
    redirect_to project_path(@project)  
  end 
end
```

Comment: I think this : `@like= @project.likes.where(user:current_user).first` should work fine.

Comment: you should use toggle by `@like.first.toggle(:heart)` or `Like.toggle(:heart)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toggle` is basically a class method; you can no way call it on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. You need to first isolate on object, and then you can all `toggle`.

You can call `first`, `last` or any other like method to get an object like:

```
@project.likes.where(user: current_user).first
```